# To delete the dynamically created EditTexts

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have written code to generate the dynamic EditText. Now I want to delete the perticular EditText from that, like in contacts in Android.How to achieve this functionality? Below my code showing imgaddress is Button on click of that I am adding view ie editText and imageview cancel now on clickof cancel I want to delete the editText.

```
imgaddess.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                linearlay.addView(linearlayout(_intMyLineCount));
                _intMyLineCount++;
                Log.i("Test","Increment => "+_intMyLineCount);
            }
        });


        private LinearLayout linearlayout(int _intID)
    {
        LinearLayout LLMain=new LinearLayout(this);
        LLMain.setId(_intID);  

        LLMain.addView(editText(_intID));
        LLMain.addView(imageview(_intID));
        LLMain.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        linearlayoutList.add(LLMain);
        return LLMain;
    }   


private EditText editText1(int _intID) {
        EditText editText = new EditText(this);
        editText.setId(_intID);
        editText.setHint("Phone No");
        editText.setSingleLine();
        editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        editText.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
        editTextList1.add(editText);
        return editText;
    }


private ImageView imageview(int _intID) {
        ImageView imgview=new ImageView(this);
        imgview.setId(_intID);
        imgview.setImageResource(R.drawable.cancel_4);
        imageViewList.add(imgview);
        return imgview;
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to insert imageView and editText and delete editText on imgaddess click?

Comment: yes exactly same functionality I want

Comment: Ok, So which editText you want to be deleted at imgaddess click? The editText that you have added with that imageaddress?

Comment: By above code I am getting one EditText and Exact infront of it one imageview for delete,So onclick of that image respective editText should get deleted

Comment: Just post my answer, please check

Answer (score 2):

I normally use `editText.setVisibility(EditText.GONE);`
and

`editText = null;` should have it garbage collected.

Comment: yes that could be done but my problem is that how to get the dynamic EditText

Comment: of course you would need to store the reference of your EditText controls in some array/arraylist. You can do it in your editText method.

Comment: I stored it in arraylist but we dont know which editText user want to delete so onclick of thatperticular imagebutton how to delete it

Comment: Won't the position of edittext/ImageButton in your list of EditText's match the index of that particular EditText in the arraylist. Since I don't have access to your code, you will have to find a way by which the current position/index of the ImageButton being clicked can be got. Once you get that, go and remove the Edittext corresponding to that position/index from the ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete EditText from its parent

```
((ViewGroup) editTextToBeDeleted.getParent()).removeView(editTextToBeDeleted);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you imageview and Exittext has same _intID. So Set onclickListener on imageView.

When imageView is clicked find its ID and now find ExitText which has same ID.(For this you will have maintain an array of ExitTexts added)

Once we have EditText corresponding to the cancel imageView, We can do exitText.setVisibility(EditText.GONE);

Here is Pseudo Code for it.

```
imageview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        // Iterate on ExitText array and check if(exitText.getID() == v.getID())
        //Now we have exitText with same ID as of imageView. So remove it.
        exitText.setVisibility(EditText.GONE);                
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the editText like this.

```
 imgaddess.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            LinearLayout LLMain = (LinearLayout)linearlayoutList.get((Integer)v.getTag());
            EditText editText = (EditText)LLMain.getChildAt(0);
            //Now hide it
            editText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
 private ImageView imageview(int _intID) {
    ImageView imgview=new ImageView(this);
    imgview.setId(_intID);
    //Adding Tag in order to get postion.
    imgview.setTag(_intID);
    imgview.setImageResource(R.drawable.cancel_4);
    imageViewList.add(imgview);
    return imgview;
}
```

Hope this will help you.